# Malware from TPB(piratebay) infected my pc. I need to transfer my data into external hdd before wiping my hard drive

Tags: malware, ubuntu, data-recovery, windows-10

OS: Windows (Primary), Ubuntu (secondary). Few days back I was using TPB(piratebay) obviously for educational purposes,even though I have ad-blocker at the time of browsing some advertisement did pop-up. So a video file that I downloaded asked me to play it on windows media player and then asked me to download some sort of codecs from the internet to run that file.

On doing so my computer all of sudden gets bombarded with advertisements in my desktop, instead of browser. This virus also disables my default Microsoft anti-virus, at the time of attack I did not have any other ant-virus. I also disable temporarily my admin privilege after restart but that I changed from the setting. So I used Adware to try to remove these advertisements, but I didn't work effectively, it deleted few files but then got stuck in middle. So I then used free version of Avast, it although removed those advertisements but I am sure the malware is still in the computer.

My antivirus is not able to find this malware. So I have dual-booted my laptop, with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. My main goal is to transfer the important data i.e. few projects, pictures, and lectures etc to my external hard drives. I am thinking as this malware should not have no effect in linux therefor I could transfer my data using Ubuntu maybe. A friend of mine also suggested the virus from TPB is pretty serious, and there is some software with updated virus definitions which I could burn in CD and then run it while booting up my pc.

But I am not sure what to do now, how can I get my data without getting malware into my external hard drive. Has any one faced similar problem ?

Can any one please tell how to fix this problem ?

Comment: In case you were wondering about the malware you were suckered into running: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106188/can-a-rogue-wmv-file-hijack-windows-media-player

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off-topic here, but more on-topic on SuperUser. Migrating.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Please flag your question for it to be migrated there or to be closed. Please do not cross-post. You may post on AskUbuntu once you delete your question or it gets closed.

Comment: Note: it's not possible to re-migrate an already migrated question. Also, this question is fine for [su]

Answer (score 0):

You are right that your Linux file systems should not have been affected.  While it's not possible to be 100% sure of anything, it is as rare as a flying panda.

Copying your data over to your Linux filesystems would therefore be a good idea.  Even in the rare cases of viruses that attach themselves to documents, like macro viruses (unlikely your case), opening it on a clean computer with proper antivirus protection is typically very safe.

While your friend is right that there are ways to do a more thorough computer scan to clean it without reinstalling, you would never know if it really cleaned everything.  That is a risk no one should take as viruses are developed to be hard to identify and often open back-doors that antiviruses won't notice.

Comment: thanks, for the info. I am thinking I should primarily do a boot time scan and then copy the content using ubuntu and then clean swipe my pc's drive.

Comment: That would be a waste of time and effort.  You should simply boot Ubuntu, copy your files and then reinstall Windows.  Of course you will then need to repair your grub install with a boot disk.

Comment: My doubt is: if the malware is in the files too, which I don't know if it can get into them or not, but if it is then although that malware may not get triggered in Linux but when used in windows it may again infect the fresh copy of OS. I am not sure what is the nature and mechanism of this Malware.

Comment: As I included in my answer, that type of malware would normally be quite inoffensive if you have a good antivirus installed and won't run by itself (need to be manually opened).  It is also quite uncommon nowadays.

Comment: thanks. Although, the problem with most antivirus is how they spike up disk usage and also at times end up deleting some windows file or registry, at-least that is what Avast did to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot Ubuntu from CD or DVD (live) if you are afraid that virus has infected linux partitions. When you copy files to your external HDD, be sure that hidden files and folders in Linux file manager that you are using are visible, so you can see exactly what you are copying (just your files, not some suspicious new files that malware had created).
Afrer that, your files are on safe, disconnect external HDD, and format all Windows accessible partitions. Don't clean them with antivirus. 
When you install fresh Windows, install some good antivirus and scan saved data on external HDD. Maybe you can do that with 2 or 3 different antivirus tools.